# Laravel form with two submit button and resource controller

Tags: laravel

I have 2 submit buttons- 1 for "save", 1 for "show saved list".
I want if  "subbutton" is clicked, redirect to *resource controller* public function store(Request $request), if "list" is clicked- redirect to *resource controller*  public function index().
My functions work well. But I dont know how to link them with different buttons.

**create.blade.php**

```
<button type="submit" value="subbutton" name="subbutton" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>
<button type="submit" value="list" name="list" class="btn btn-primary">SHOW</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion would be to transform your listing `button` to an `a` tag

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.index') }}" class="btn btn-primary">SHOW</a>
```

thereby, the submit button would carry out the form submission and the anchor tag would list the resources.